# Use variable to change machine type in Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-build

In cloud build trigger I created a `variable: key _MACHINE_TYPE value: E2_HIGHCPU_8`

I set this variable in my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
 steps:
  # Build Backend image and push with kaniko
  - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
    id: '[Backend] Build & Push image'
    args:
      - --dockerfile=backend/Dockerfile
      - --destination=$_BACKEND_IMAGE_REPO:$_APP_VERSION
      - --destination=$_BACKEND_IMAGE_REPO:$_PROJECT
      - --cache=true
      - --build-arg=user=user
      - --build-arg=uid=1000
      - --context=/workspace/backend
      - --target=production

  # Build Frontend image and push with kaniko
  - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
    id: '[Frontend] Build & Push image'
    args:
      - --dockerfile=frontend/Dockerfile
      - --destination=$_FRONTEND_IMAGE_REPO:$_APP_VERSION
      - --destination=$_FRONTEND_IMAGE_REPO:$_PROJECT
      - --cache=true
      - --build-arg=REACT_APP_VERSION=$_APP_VERSION
      - --build-arg=REACT_APP_WEBSITE_NAME=$_WEBSITE_NAME
      - --build-arg=REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL=$_BACKEND_URL
      - --build-arg=REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_KEY=$_GOOGLE_MAP_KEY
      - --context=/workspace/frontend
      - --target=production

  # Laravel Migration
  - name: 'gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper'
    id: 'Laravel Migration'
    args: [
      '-i', $_BACKEND_IMAGE_REPO:$_PROJECT,
      '-e', 'DB_CONNECTION=$_DB_CONNECTION',
      '-e', 'DB_SOCKET=$_DB_SOCKET',
      '-e', 'DB_PORT=$_DB_PORT',
      '-e', 'DB_DATABASE=$_DB_DATABASE',
      '-e', 'DB_USERNAME=$_DB_USERNAME',
      '-e', 'DB_PASSWORD=$_DB_PASSWORD',
      '-s', $_DB_INSTANCE_NAME,
      '--', 'scripts/migration.sh', '--config=$_MIGRATION_CONFIG'
    ]
    waitFor:
      - '[Backend] Build & Push image'
      - '[Frontend] Build & Push image'

 # Deploy Backend image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    id: '[Backend] Cloud Run Deployment'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: [
      'run', 'deploy', '$_BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME',
      '--image', '$_BACKEND_IMAGE_REPO:$_PROJECT', 
      '--region', '$_REGION',
      '--update-env-vars', 'APP_VERSION=$TAG_NAME'
    ]
    waitFor:
      - '[Backend] Build & Push image'
      - '[Frontend] Build & Push image'
      - 'Laravel Migration'

  # Deploy Frontend image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    id: '[Frontend] Cloud Run Deployment'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: [
      'run', 'deploy', '$_FRONTEND_SERVICE_NAME',
      '--image', '$_FRONTEND_IMAGE_REPO:$_PROJECT',
      '--region', '$_REGION'
    ]
    waitFor:
      - '[Backend] Build & Push image'
      - '[Frontend] Build & Push image'
      - 'Laravel Migration'
      - '[Backend] Cloud Run Deployment'

  # Deploy Cloud Scheduler Crons
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    id: 'Deploy Cloud Scheduler Crons'
    env:
      - 'PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID'
      - 'PROJECT=$_PROJECT'
      - 'REGION=$_REGION'
      - 'BACKEND_URL=$_BACKEND_URL'
      - 'TASK_MANAGER_TOKEN=$_TASK_MANAGER_TOKEN'
      - 'TASK_PAUSE=$_TASK_PAUSE'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./create-crons.sh']

 options:
  dynamic_substitutions: true
  substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
  machineType: $_MACHINE_TYPE
 timeout: 3600s
```

But I have this error when I start my pipeline:

```
failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: unknown value "\"$_MACHINE_TYPE\"" for enum google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.BuildOptions.MachineType`
```

How can I use a variable to change the machine type with a substitution ?

Comment: You can change that dynamically.

Comment: @John I have tried to reproduce the issue. but, I am able to build successfully. can you share your complete `.yaml` file?

Comment: @RoopaM If I set `E2_HIGHCPU_8` in my .yaml it works but if I use substitution I got the error. All other substitutions are working but this substitution under `options` is ignored. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) documentation states that, Use substitutions in your build's steps and images to resolve their values at build time. So, variable substitutions are only available for use within these two steps.  The [BuildOptions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build.BuildOptions) object would be a different object and therefore it is not qualified for this type of variable substitution.

If you really need to use variable substitution, consider using the [`gcloud builds submit`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--machine-type) command line instead, then call it with the `--machine-type` flag.

Comment: Hi thank for your answer. Ok I see but I'm using Cloud build trigger so I don't use a command to startmy build. My pipeline is triggered on `git new tag`

Comment: @John Currently, It is not possible to use the substitution variable for `BuildOptions.MachineType`. that’s the reason I shared a workaround. If it is necessary for your project, you can raise a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190802)